# How can i correct this SQL query & optimize it?

Tags: sql, database, analytics, business-intelligence, database-administration

I am running this SQL query and it is giving me an error, When i re-arrange the columns and make DISTINCT k.Column_1 come first it works but then runs forever and seems to an expensive one. How can i correct this, optimize it etc?

```
SELECT 
k.Column_2, DISTINCT k.Column_1, s.Column_3, s.Column_4, s.Column_5, s.Column_6, s.Column_7,
s.Column_8, s.Column_9, s.Column_10, s.Column_11, t.Column_5,
t.Column_6, t.Column_7, t.Column_8, t.Column_9, t.Column_10,
t.Column_11, r.Column_3,
p.Column_2, p.Column_3, p.Column_4, p.5, p.Column_6, p.Column_7, p.Column_8, p.Column_9
FROM table_1 k
LEFT JOIN table_2 s
ON k.Column_1 = s.Column_1
LEFT JOIN table_3 t
ON k.Column_1 = t.Column_1
LEFT table_4 r
ON k.Column_1 = r.Column_1
LEFT JOIN table_5 p
ON k.Column_1 = p.Column_1
```

I am now running this edited SQL Query and it is running forever, i would like to optimize it if possible.

Column_1 is the index.

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.Column_1, k.MONTH, 
SUM(s.Column_3) Column_3, 
SUM(s.Column_4) Column_4, 
SUM(s.Column_5) Column_5, 
SUM(s.Column_6) Column_6, 
SUM(s.Column_7) Column_7,
SUM(s.Column_8) Column_8, 
SUM(s.Column_9) Column_9, 
SUM(s.Column_10) Column_10, 
SUM(s.Column_11) Column_11, 
SUM(t.Column_5) Column_5,
SUM(t.Column_6) Column_6, 
SUM(t.Column_7) t.Column_7, 
SUM(t.Column_8) Column_8, 
SUM(t.Column_9) Column_9, 
SUM(t.Column_10) Column_10,
SUM(t.Column_11) Column_11, 
SUM(r.Column_3) Column_3,
SUM(p.Column_2) Column_2, 
SUM(p.Column_3) Column_3, 
SUM(p.Column_4) Column_4, 
SUM(p.Column_5) Column_5, 
SUM(p.Column_6) Column_6, 
SUM(p.Column_7) Column_7, 
SUM(p.Column_8) Column_8, 
SUM(p.Column_9) Column_9
FROM table_1 k
LEFT JOIN table_2 s
ON k.Column_1 = s.Column_1
LEFT JOIN table_3 t
ON k.Column_1 = t.Column_1
LEFT table_4 r
ON k.Column_1 = r.Column_1
LEFT JOIN table_5 p
ON k.Column_1 = p.Column_1
GROUP BY k.Column_1, k.MONTH
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not what you really want to do.  I would suggest asking another question with a reduced number of joins and examples of input data and desired results.

Comment: Distinct is always an expensive operation, How big is table_1? You might be able to make this faster with a derived table. Also s.k.column_4 doesn't make sense. Which table is column_4 in?

Comment: Please describe some of what the meaning of the data is here. It makes a difference in how to present the query. Since you can't distinct only one column, what are you trying to achieve? Give us so before and after data to show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ASlo what indexes do you have?

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT k.Column_1,` is incorrect and wrong syntax. `distinct` keyword applies to the entire set of attributes you are fetching and not per column .

It should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.Column_2, k.Column_1, s.Column_3, s.k.Column_4, s.Column_5, ....
```

Comment: Note that you can use distinct on one column with aggregate functions: ``SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) FROM Table GROUP BY ColumnA``.  Counts the distinct Column B's and not all of the Column B's.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I tried to re-arrange that and it is running forever. Any help on optimizing the script?

Comment: @LivingstoneKaramage, post a separate question for that with table structure, index information for all the table along with generated query plan

Answer (score 0):

One big thing to take into consideration is that joins can return a lot more combinations then you may expect. For instance, take these two tables.

```
Table_A  Table_B
+-----+  +-----+
|Var_A|  |Var_B|
+-----+  +-----+
|  2  |  |  2  |
|  2  |  |  2  |
|  2  |  |  4  |
|  4  |  +-----+
+-----+
```

If you run

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.var_a = table_b.var_b
```

You'll get this mess, because it's matching every possible combination of values between var_a and var_b

```
+-----+-----+
|Var_A|Var_B|
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  4  |  4  |
+-----+-----+
```

To avoid running into this issue, make your joins more restrictive by joining on more fields, even if you ultimately don't end up using them.